# Unexpected error when creating new list record with a Person or Group column

Tags: 2010, list, column

I need to create a simple list with an AD user column but when I try to add a new item I get an 'Unexpected error' **if the username has been checked**, if the username has not been checked and corresponds to a user in the AD I can proceed and it saves correctly.

The unexpected error message is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToXmlQualifiedName(String value, Boolean decodeName)     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read1_Object(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read2_DictionaryEntry(Boolean checkType)     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read3_ArrayOfDictionaryEntry()

Which doesn't help me much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spre3,

I had the same problem and for a long time there were no answers out there for anybody.  Then I saw the question [hotfix for problem with SharePoint PeopleEditor in IE-9](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27251/hotfix-for-problem-with-sharepoint-peopleeditor-in-ie-9/34150#34150) and a person there had posted an answer that led me in the right direction.  You could try his solution or mine, which I also posted as an answer to that question.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: You deserve more likes for spreading this article.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. Your pages probably tell IE to use IE9 standards, i.e. you have a

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

tag in your master page.

The problem is, this doesn't work with people picker. Please see this discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/90b3835c-6754-4bb6-9fd4-b74f16f236ff.

I haven't found a fix yet, just saw the workaround mentioned in the discussion -- i.e. you have to go back to using IE8 standards. That's not a good option for us, because we'd like to use CSS3.

Comment: jaleikas, please follow the link in my answer, there is a solution there.